# Which nuget feed (source) should I use for .NET Core RC2 and 1.0?

Tags: asp.net-core, nuget, .net-core

I have seen different suggestions about using a specific nuget feed for working with .NET core RC2 and 1.0 applications. I'm getting a bit confused as I don't find any official information anywhere.

What is the right/best setup of nuget feeds (sources) when working with .NET core?

I'm only targeting this framework net46 (target framework monikor). Does this change the answer?

For your information my nuget.config under .../AppData/Roaming/NuGet looks like this:

```
  <activePackageSource>
    <add key="aspnetmasterci" value="https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetcirelease/api/v3/index.json" />
  </activePackageSource>
...
  <packageSources>
    <add key="aspnetmaster" value="https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetmaster/api/v3/index.json" />
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
    <add key="aspnetmasterci" value="https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetcirelease/api/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the default nuget.org feed, for dotnet core 1.0.

Aspnet feed are details in the aspnet announcement Github repository here :

- https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/199

For corefx (base framework) :

- https://dotnet.myget.org/gallery/dotnet-core

Source : Readme.md file in this repos

- https://github.com/aspnet/Home
- https://github.com/dotnet/corefx